# Button not visible over GPUImageView

Tags: gpuimage

This is no doubt something basic I'm overlooking but I'm not able to get a button to display over a GPUImageView video display. I'm using a subview to display the cropped video to part of the screen using this code which is working as expected.

filterView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 568, 240)];
    [self.view addSubview:filterView];

I'm using an iphone storyboard, the button is  below / as a subview? in the list, I've tried Editor/Arrange/send to front any hints. The button is definately there as I can get it to display if I position it in the portion of the screen not covered by the filterView.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding it as a subview of the GPUImageView? A GPUImageView (on iOS) is merely a UIView with a CAEAGLLayer backing, so it should behave like any other UIView. Something sounds like it's not being laid out properly in your view hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks Brad, sage advice again, thanks for helping out beginners like me. I have fixed it by using 2 container views in a parent(?) view controller, now the buttons appear and work,  so yes it was badly constructed view hierarchy.